# react-redux handling multiple data with redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am trying to set a global state using redux and it works when I try to pass single data but not working when I try to pass multiple data. Below is my code:

```
<CSButton
           onPress={() => {
                          this.setState({
                            comment   : this.state.comment,
                            region  : this.state.region,            
                           },
                    () => this.props.commentHandler(this.state),
                          this.props.regionHandler(this.state), 
           // I am getting correct answer when I console.log here         
                    () => console.log(this.props.comment,'this.props.comment?'),
                    () => console.log(this.props.region,'this.props.region?'))}}>
           <Text>Button</Text>
          </CSButton>

//when I try to console.log using another button, works fine for 'this.props.comment'

           <Button
                    title='comment'
                    onPress={()=> console.log(this.props.comment,'comment')}>
          </Button>

    //But when I try to console.log `this.props.region` it gives me undefined

          <Button
                title='region'
                onPress={()=> console.log(this.props.region,'region')}>
          </Button>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        region   : state.region,
        comment  : state.comment,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        regionHandler  : (state) => dispatch({ type: 'REGION', payload: state.region}),
        commentHandler : (state) => dispatch({ type: 'COMMENT', payload: state.comment}),

    }
}
```

App.js

```
const initialState = {
    comment:'',
    region:[],
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action);
    switch (action.type)
    {
        case 'COMMENT':
            return { comment: action.payload}
        case 'REGION':
            return { region: action.payload}
    }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
```

It seems that my code is only calling the first handler which is `this.props.commentHandler(this.state)` but not the second one `this.props.regionHandler(this.state)`.

Is there a way I could fix this issue? Any advise or comments would be really appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the codes of your actions and reducer?

Comment: @IsuruAbeywardana I just did it thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned your initial state to the state`state = initialState` but never used. every time you trigger an action you send a new object to the view. You have to set it to the state.

Try this out. You have to do this in immutable way.

```
   const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type)
        {
            case 'COMMENT':
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    comment: action.payload,
                }
                break;
            case 'REGION':
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    region: action.payload,
                }
                break;
        }
        return state
    }
```

And I just noticed you missed `breaks;` in your code.

If you have a doubts about immutable state tree. refer this free video series. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsle5quS7A&list=PL55RiY5tL51rrC3sh8qLiYHqUV3twEYU_)

Comment: wow! you are correct! thanks so much! It would be great if  you could explain what is happening? I want to know what i did wrong.

Comment: @kirimi It is pleasure to help you. I updated the answer.  refer this video If you do not understand it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bMTJxvEJiE&index=4&list=PL55RiY5tL51rrC3sh8qLiYHqUV3twEYU_

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState(partialState, callback)` takes only one callback function. You are passing it two functions here:

```
 () => this.props.commentHandler(this.state),
       this.props.regionHandler(this.state),
```

Instead try:

```
() => {
  this.props.commentHandler(this.state)
  this.props.regionHandler(this.state)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. Yea I thought about this and tried but it gives me the same results.